# How to run method after page load is complete in metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, async-await

I am trying to run a method called drawMoveLines() after my game page is fully loaded. This method, drawMoveLines(), draws lines between objects on my game page. However, when I try to run it at the bottom of my game page's main method, the lines go all screwy as the objects have not yet loaded correctly. (it works fine though when I run it off a button located in the game page)

I believe the path to go down involves asynchronous programming, but as my handle on this concept is rather primitive, any help in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Page.Loaded` event?

Comment: @svick Thanks for the tip but cannot find this event in C# 5.0. The System.Web.UI namespace does not exist for metro apps. If I am doing it wrong, please enlighten me :)

Comment: I thought you were talking about [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page), which does have `Loaded` event. If that's not what you meant, then you should make that clear.

Comment: @svick Thanks for the reply. That IS what I meant. I realized I had been researching Page.Load, not Page.Loaded as you had recommended. My apologies. Unfortunately however, I am still at a loss on how to implement this event and run my desired method. Can you show me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Have found the correct syntax. It is as follows.

```
//This here
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);

//Calls this event
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         drawMoveLines();
     }
```